# Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply EF6 with Interceptor

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Oke, I have a lot of headache from banging my head against the wall the last couple of days. With Entity Framework 6.1.3, I have created an Interceptor in order to implement soft-delete functionality to my application. The interceptor works like a charm most of the time, but at a certain moment, we encounter an exception, which is sent by SQL Server: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply.

The interceptor:

```
Public Class SoftDeleteInterceptor
Implements Interception.IDbCommandTreeInterceptor

Public Const SoftDeleteColumnName = "Deprecated"

Public Sub TreeCreated(interceptionContext As Interception.DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext) Implements Interception.IDbCommandTreeInterceptor.TreeCreated
    If interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace = Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.SSpace Then
        Dim queryCommand = TryCast(interceptionContext.Result, Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree)
        If queryCommand IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not queryCommand.Query.ExpressionKind = DbExpressionKind.NewInstance Then
            Dim expression = queryCommand.Query.Accept(New SoftDeleteQueryVisitor())
            Dim query = New DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace, queryCommand.DataSpace, expression)
            interceptionContext.Result = query
        End If

        Dim deleteCommand = TryCast(interceptionContext.OriginalResult, DbDeleteCommandTree)
        If deleteCommand IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim type = Common.Reflection.GetEntityTypeFromString(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType.Name, True)
            If Not type Is Nothing Then
                If type.GetInterfaces.Contains(GetType(ISoftDelete)) Then
                    Dim setClauses = New List(Of DbModificationClause)
                    Dim table = DirectCast(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType, Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)
                    If table.Properties.Any(Function(p) p.Name = SoftDeleteColumnName) Then
                        setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(DbExpressionBuilder.[Property](DbExpressionBuilder.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType, deleteCommand.Target.VariableName), SoftDeleteColumnName), DbExpression.FromBoolean(True)))
                    End If

                    Dim update = New DbUpdateCommandTree(deleteCommand.MetadataWorkspace, deleteCommand.DataSpace, deleteCommand.Target, deleteCommand.Predicate, setClauses.AsReadOnly(), Nothing)
                    interceptionContext.Result = update
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

It adds an ExpressionVisitor (called SoftDeleteQueryVisitor) to every query command.

The ExpressionVisitor:

```
Public Class SoftDeleteQueryVisitor
Inherits Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DefaultExpressionVisitor

Public Const SoftDeleteColumnName = "Deprecated"

Public Overrides Function Visit(expression As DbScanExpression) As DbExpression

    Dim type = Common.Reflection.GetEntityTypeFromString(expression.Target.Name, True)
    If Not type Is Nothing Then
        If type.GetInterfaces.Contains(GetType(ISoftDelete)) Then
            Dim table = DirectCast(expression.Target.ElementType, Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType)
            If table.Properties.Any(Function(p) p.Name = SoftDeleteColumnName) Then
                Dim binding = expression.Bind()
                Return binding.Filter(binding.VariableType.Variable(binding.VariableName).Property(SoftDeleteColumnName).Equal(DbExpression.FromBoolean(False)))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.Visit(expression)

End Function

End Class
```

This does the trick. No "Deprecated" records are queried from the database. But after a few queries, the Nested too deeply exception is thrown. When I then examine the generated query by Entity Framework, my headache gets even worse (I have deleted most of the where clauses, for readability purposes):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], 
    [Extent1].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 
    [Extent1].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], 
    [Extent1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent1].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated], 
    [Extent1].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary]
    FROM ( SELECT [Var_130].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_130].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_130].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_130].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_130].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_130].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_130].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_130].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_130].[City] AS [City], [Var_130].[State] AS [State], [Var_130].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_130].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_130].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_130].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_130].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_130].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_130].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_130].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
        FROM ( SELECT [Var_131].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_131].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_131].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_131].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_131].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_131].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_131].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_131].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_131].[City] AS [City], [Var_131].[State] AS [State], [Var_131].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_131].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_131].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_131].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_131].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_131].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_131].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_131].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
            FROM ( SELECT [Var_132].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_132].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_132].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_132].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_132].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_132].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_132].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_132].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_132].[City] AS [City], [Var_132].[State] AS [State], [Var_132].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_132].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_132].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_132].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_132].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_132].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_132].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_132].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                FROM ( SELECT [Var_133].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_133].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_133].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_133].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_133].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_133].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_133].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_133].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_133].[City] AS [City], [Var_133].[State] AS [State], [Var_133].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_133].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_133].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_133].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_133].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_133].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_133].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_133].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                    FROM ( SELECT [Var_134].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_134].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_134].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_134].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_134].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_134].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_134].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_134].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_134].[City] AS [City], [Var_134].[State] AS [State], [Var_134].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_134].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_134].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_134].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_134].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_134].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_134].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_134].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                        FROM ( SELECT [Var_135].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_135].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_135].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_135].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_135].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_135].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_135].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_135].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_135].[City] AS [City], [Var_135].[State] AS [State], [Var_135].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_135].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_135].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_135].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_135].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_135].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_135].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_135].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                            FROM ( SELECT [Var_136].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_136].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_136].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_136].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_136].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_136].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_136].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_136].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_136].[City] AS [City], [Var_136].[State] AS [State], [Var_136].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_136].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_136].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_136].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_136].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_136].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_136].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_136].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                FROM ( SELECT [Var_137].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_137].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_137].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_137].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_137].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_137].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_137].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_137].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_137].[City] AS [City], [Var_137].[State] AS [State], [Var_137].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_137].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_137].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_137].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_137].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_137].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_137].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_137].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                    FROM ( SELECT [Var_138].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_138].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_138].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_138].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_138].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_138].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_138].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_138].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_138].[City] AS [City], [Var_138].[State] AS [State], [Var_138].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_138].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_138].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_138].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_138].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_138].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_138].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_138].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                        FROM ( SELECT [Var_139].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_139].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_139].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_139].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_139].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_139].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_139].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_139].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_139].[City] AS [City], [Var_139].[State] AS [State], [Var_139].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_139].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_139].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_139].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_139].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_139].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_139].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_139].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                            FROM ( SELECT [Var_140].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_140].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_140].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_140].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_140].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_140].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_140].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_140].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_140].[City] AS [City], [Var_140].[State] AS [State], [Var_140].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_140].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_140].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_140].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_140].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_140].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_140].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_140].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                                FROM ( SELECT [Var_141].[AddressID] AS [AddressID], [Var_141].[LinkedEntityID] AS [LinkedEntityID], [Var_141].[Type] AS [Type], [Var_141].[Status] AS [Status], [Var_141].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Var_141].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], [Var_141].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], [Var_141].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], [Var_141].[City] AS [City], [Var_141].[State] AS [State], [Var_141].[Country] AS [Country], [Var_141].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_141].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], [Var_141].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_141].[ModifiedAt] AS [ModifiedAt], [Var_141].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], [Var_141].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], [Var_141].[Deprecated] AS [Deprecated]
                                                        )  AS [Var_142]
                                                        WHERE [Var_142].[Deprecated] = 0
                                                    )  AS [Var_141]
                                                    WHERE [Var_141].[Deprecated] = 0
                                                )  AS [Var_140]
                                                WHERE [Var_140].[Deprecated] = 0
                                            )  AS [Var_139]
                                            WHERE [Var_139].[Deprecated] = 0
                                        )  AS [Var_138]
                                        WHERE [Var_138].[Deprecated] = 0
                                    )  AS [Var_137]
                                    WHERE [Var_137].[Deprecated] = 0
                                )  AS [Var_136]
                                WHERE [Var_136].[Deprecated] = 0
                            )  AS [Var_135]
                            WHERE [Var_135].[Deprecated] = 0
                        )  AS [Var_134]
                        WHERE [Var_134].[Deprecated] = 0
                    )  AS [Var_133]
                    WHERE [Var_133].[Deprecated] = 0
                )  AS [Var_132]
                WHERE [Var_132].[Deprecated] = 0
            )  AS [Var_131]
            WHERE [Var_131].[Deprecated] = 0
        )  AS [Var_130]
        WHERE [Var_130].[Deprecated] = 0
    )  AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[AddressID] = '381a335b-0992-44aa-bee3-21088d640a6c'
```

This is an extremely complicated way to achieve "WHERE Depricated = 0" and obviously not working! Does anyone know what's going on with my code and EF6?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does removing the part "If table.Properties.Any(Function(p) p.Name = SoftDeleteColumnName) Then" help?.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately not, it is there to detect if the queried table has the soft-delete column ("Deprecated").